# How do I read a script array into duktape?

Tags: duktape

I'm new to duktape and trying to read a config
from a script file:

```
var config = 
[
{ ready: true, name: "dev1", on: 8,  off:  9 },
{ ready: true, name: "dev2", on: 10, off: 11 },
{ ready: true, name: "dev3", on: 18, off: 21 },
{ ready: true, name: "dev4", on: 13, off: 17 }
];
```

duktape has great documentation, but I can not seem to find
any example of what I am trying to accomplish.

I have managed to read a single dimension array. (Not sure if it is the best or proper way to to do it)

```
// var one_dim = [ "hello", "world", "single", "dimension", "array" ] ;

void init_one_dimension(void) {

  duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -1, "one_dim");

  if(duk_is_array(ctx, -1)) {
    printf("Found array\n");
    duk_enum(ctx, -1, DUK_ENUM_ARRAY_INDICES_ONLY); 

    while (duk_next(ctx, -1 , 0 )) {

      duk_get_prop_index(ctx, -1, 0);
      duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -4, duk_get_string(ctx, -1));
      printf("%s\n", duk_get_string(ctx, -1));
      show_stack(ctx, "STACK");

      duk_pop(ctx); // get_prop_string
      duk_pop(ctx); // get_prop_index
      duk_pop(ctx); // duk_next
    }

    duk_pop(ctx); // duk_enum
    duk_pop(ctx); // duk_get_prop_string
  }
}
```

Multi-dimensional arrays escape me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated: If the object is not an array, you pop one time to often. one pop should be outside the if-namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The 'config' object you have at the top, is not a multi-dimensional array but instead an array containing dictionaries. So with the enum code you have already, you just need to access the keys (ready, name, etc) like normal object properties.

> [duk_get_prop_string](http://duktape.org/api.html#duk_get_prop_string)